# Right-click on image save image as in selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am stuck at a point when trying to save an image to the hard drive using the selenium
I need a way to right-click on the image and click "Save image as" from the context menu
All what I could do is to right-click on the image

```
.FindElementByXPath("//img[@src='/resource.jsp']").ClickContext
```

How can I select Save Image As option for the image or even better to download the image to the hard drive directly
The problem is that I can't use the image URL to download it .. so I have no way except to use the Right-click menu ..
Any ideas?

Comment: you're outside of the DOM at that point.  You could take a screenshot.

Comment: No I don't want to take screen shot. I know how to do that. All what I need is to download the image using Right-click and interact with the context menu..

Comment: What is the jsp page returning here?  Base-64 encoded image?  If so, it might be pretty easy to grab that.

Comment: @pcalkins I don't know exactly. How can I know what is returning ?? It is dynamic image ..

Comment: some thing similar to contextClick perform then sendkeys up/down and enter

Comment: @QHarr Can you show me how to do that ..?

Comment: Not at present as I have no selenium basic and get malicious software warnings from the download site (not sure if true but not sure I want to chance at present).

Comment: @YasserKhalil, use the browser's inspector.   It should have a list of resources/media if the object itself isn't inspectable with a right-click (does it show "/resource.jsp" when you do that?).  Btw, Selenium's "sendKeys" won't work here, it's outside the DOM.  VBA's sendKeys may work... though I'm not familiar with that...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I chose to take snapshot of the element itself and I think this is working well.